# Looking for CoProcessors to go along side an Allwinner SoC in a budget Game Console

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard, performance, video-game-console

I'm currently eyeing the A and H lines of SoCs produced by allwinnertech.com, for use in an affordable, yet high performance game console.

I have considered using multiple SoCs in one design to get greater performance, but I'm worried about hardware redundancy in functions like connectivity.

So, instead I'm considering a design utilizing a single SoC and some number of soon to be selected CoProcessors.

Issue is I don't know where to find the CoProcessors. I know graphics coprocessors exists, in the form of GPU chips, but I need something affordable.

So I'm looking for more ICs in the Allwinner's price range, which are better specialized for compute, both graphics and general purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a range in USDs? And what quantities are you looking at? Also, keep in mind that designing such a device takes a lot of money and time.

Comment: Designing a PCB for a SoM is way easier - the hardest parts are already taken care of.

Comment: I'm looking to make an optimized system, considering all factors, including durability and inter-connectivity overhead and replacement cost. I'm assuming it won't cost much more than $100, but it really depends.

Comment: Do multiple SoM's stack well?

Comment: SoMs don't stack much better than SoCs, but you don't have to worry about connecting RAM. And working in embedded Linux I can assure you that 100$ is very hard to achieve, especially if you go for better SoCs and consider the R&D costs.

Comment: Update: Allwinner's R-Series seems to be a good option for CPU-CoProcessing.

Answer (score 1):

After our discussion in comments and looking at your requirements - you probably want to go with the nVidia Tegra. As a SoM not as a bare SoC. That's roughly the chip which powers the Nintendo Switch. They did port the Witcher onto it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if my goal should be to reinvent the switch. I have discovered a valid CPU-Coprocessor: Allwinner's R-Series.

Comment: I'm open to GPU coprocessor's though. Possibly from Nvidia, Intel, AMD, ARM, RISCV, or someone else, who has something in my power envelope.

Comment: https://www.amd.com/en/products/embedded

Comment: https://alibaba.com/showroom/gpu-chip.html

Comment: https://wccftech.com/nvidia-hopper-gpu-mcm-leaked/

Comment: https://shakti.org.in